# Cannot SSH into EC2 AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've tried several hours, I used RHEL 7.1 and used ec2-user and root, rebooted the ec2 instances, generated new keys but I still seem to miss the issue - I just cannot connect to the instance, all sec groups are set for ssh.

> JohnDoe-MacBook-Pro:.ssh johndoe$ sudo ssh -vi direct
>   ec2-user@ec2-52-74-131-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
>       OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
>       debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>       debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
>       debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-74-131-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [52.74.131.174]
>   port 22.
>       debug1: Connection established.
>       debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
>       debug1: identity file direct.pem type -1
>       debug1: identity file direct.pem-cert type -1
>       debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>       debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
>       debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
>       debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH*
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>       debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
>       debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
>       debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>       debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>       debug1: Server host key: RSA e5:2e:74:ea:a3:e3:1a:82:fe:3b:fc:61:69:d0:5f:65
>       debug1: Host 'ec2-52-74-131-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
>       debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>       debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>       debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>       debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>       debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>       debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>       debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>       debug1: Trying private key: direct.pem
>       debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
>       debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
>       debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>       Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: Offtopic. This is not a programming problem. it's more server configuration. Try serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everything and restarted, I do not know what I did differently to the guide, I think I did choose an IAM role before and a subnet. Anyway I followed this guide and I could connect at once:

https://support.cloudshark.org/quick-start/aws.html